# Replacing all occurrences of a string that contains special chars in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all the occurrences of a string in javascript;

In my `search` text I have special chars and I cant escape them;

I need to replace the `${wid}` text with the given string;

I have this function:

```
    function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
        return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
    }
```

that should do the job;

```
var inner_code = replaceAll('/\$\{wid\}/', 'id_' + widget.model_attributes.id, widget.code);
```

`widget.model_attributes.id` is a positive integer number

`widget.code` is:

```
<div id="code_50"><div id="${wid}"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#${wid}").text("hello world");
</script></div>
```

p.s: this is not a duplicate question; i don't know how to escape special chars using JS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: it is not a duplicate ! it is a problem and i don't understand it

Comment: The regex constructor takes a string, so you have to double-escape all special characters, simply use a regex literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash itself. Try:

```
replaceAll('\\$\\{wid\\}', 'id_' + ...)
```

You are writing a JavaScript string literal. You want the string *content* to be "\$\{wid\}", because that is the RegExp source code you want. Since backslash means something in string literals, you need to escape it (by putting another backslash in front of it).

I would recommend not using the replaceAll function, and just writing:

```
var inner_code = widget.code.replace(/\$\{wid\}/g, 'id_' + widget.model_attributes.id);
```

That allows you to keep the RegExp as a RegExp literal, which is much easier to read than going through a string literal and the RegExp constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating your regexp correctly.  Use a literal expression:

```
function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find), replace);
}
var inner_code = replaceAll(/\${wid}/g, 'id_' + widget.model_attributes.id, widget.code);
```